# Is a transfer function with a denominator of one with V_o/V_i as the definition of the function?

Tags: transfer-function, low-pass

I've been given this question for my electronics course and have gone through it. The question asks we construct a circuit with transfer function: $$G(\omega) = 11 + j\omega 330 \times 10^{-6}$$The only way I can think this question has a solution is if a current source is used as opposed to a voltage source when you take the voltage over the output.

The answers to it say a the circuit should be a RC LPF with: $$R=33k\Omega \\C=10nF$$So I went through, drew this circuit and derived the transfer function but I can't find anyway that this configuration could have the aforementioned transfer function. Is there something I'm missing in this?

Comment: I agree, I don't see how a simple a **+** jb TF would arise from an RC LPF.

Comment: You need an active circuit to get that transfer function. Question or answer is wrong.

Comment: Note that it's **G(s)**, not **H(s)**, otherwise this would be a PD filter (zero, not pole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is NOT a lowpass function. In contrary, the output rises with increasing frequency.

The transfer function

**H(s)**=11+s(330)E-6=**11(1+30µs)**

is a function for a classical **PD-controller** (used in many control systems) with a basic gain of **Ho=11** and time constant of **tau=30µs** (R=3k and C=10nF).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at least a GAIN of 11X (which a transformer could provide, unless some Zload must be included); plus a rising response.

however, if a / is inserted between the leftmost 2 "1"s, the LPF makes sense, if 2 parentheses surround all that's after the /